# Flask send_file generates duplicate files

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Flask `send_file` to let users to download a zip file. The download function works, but the every time a user downloads a file it creates a duplicate zip file inside my `my_project/app/`. I can't seem to figure out how the duplicate files are generated.

```
@post_user_blueprint.route('/download_note/<string:ind_id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_note(ind_id):
    zip_name = "{0}_notes.zip".format(ind_id)
    upload_path = current_app.config['UPLOAD_PATH']
    path = os.path.dirname(upload_path + "/documents/" + "/{0}/".format(ind_id))
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zipf.write(path + '/' + file, basename(path + '/' + file))
    zipf.close()
    return send_file(zip_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code passes a string to the ZipFile constructor:

```
zip_name = "{0}_notes.zip".format(ind_id)
zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

ZipFile interprets the string as a filesystem location where you want to create the zipfile, for example `foo_notes.zip` in the current directory.

However you do not want to create the file on disk, you only want to create it in memory.

To do this, pass a `BytesIO` instance to `ZipFile`'s constructor rather than a string:

```
from io import BytesIO

@post_user_blueprint.route('/download_note/<string:ind_id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download_note(ind_id):
    zip_buffer = BytesIO()
    upload_path = current_app.config['UPLOAD_PATH']
    path = os.path.dirname(upload_path + "/documents/" + "/{0}/".format(ind_id))
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zipf.write(path + '/' + file, basename(path + '/' + file))
    zipf.close()
    return send_file(zip_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Now the zipfile's data will be written to the `BytesIO` instance in memory, not to disk.